# How to add and edit many tables at once? ASP .NET MVC razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am developing ASP .NET MVC aplication and i have problems with presentation layer. I am using Razor as view engine.+

I am developing CRUD aplication for three tables. Tables have autoincrement key.

First i have to enter data in first table. Then i have to enter data in second table and store that in some list and show that in grid on view. That grid have to have edit and delete columns. I have a button add second table to continue entering data in next row of second table (in grid). I have to save data in database at the end of all entering.

How i can edit those rows in a grid when i have not keys because i didnt save those in database? My idea for this is to give them some dummy id's.

I cant pass to controller whole row as object item?

My plan for UI for this aplication was to have ViewModel which have those three models as parametars and one List for multiple model. Then, to have four Views, three for models and one with view of models and grid.

Is that a good idea?

All three models have same ViewModel as model for view, and i have problems passing that model between views. So i dont know is my plan wrong?

What is the usualy solution for this kind of problems when you have to add and edit many tables and at the end to store data for all tables in database?

I hope that i explain my problem well. Thank you.

Comment: There are multiple questions in here. May be you should start and ask a specific question if you are stuck.

Comment: I write as answer one concrete question.

Answer (score 1):

you can use guid as id

```
Guid.NewGuid();
```

it can solve your id problem
about Model , its okay to use 3 list as a model properties
or lazy loading those three list separately using ajax if data is large.

you can store those data in session but what happens if web server (iis) recycles your application pool or server shutdowns suddenly??

its better to persist your data in some database (if its not worthing to create tables in sql, you can use some nosql storage as redis or mongodb)